# Automatically signing in a customer through browser who has authenticated with token based authentication

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

The usecase here is a mobile app that will create an account for the customer using token based authentication. Using this i can do everything i want from the app. The idea is that the app tells Magento when the phone has reached a certain GPS coordinate, which puts the customer in a Group that is allowed to purchase an otherwise "locked" product.

However when it comes time for the customer to actually purchase something, i want to spawn a browser from the app on the phone and automatically log the user in (either iframe or an actual browser is fine).

I have been considering simply pointing the newly spawned browser at an url that takes in a GET parameter, perhaps the hashed token, or maybe the username and password as long as we do HTTPS. Not entirely sure how I would deal with this in my Magento 2 module.

Are there any other or more straight forward ways of doing this ? Can i get a session somehow and "prime it" ? 
What about using something like Facebook auth ?

Comment: Why don't you make a CURL call to authenticate your user and retrieve a token from that? It would prevent your user from seeing some kind of iframe or another tab.